# CommandError: Unexpected response when fetching version info from Expo servers: undefined. react native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Hello Everyone I am having an issue on my expo app. When I'm trying to run npm start command the following error apears

```
CommandError: Unexpected response when fetching version info from Expo servers: undefined.
```

I have node version 16.15.0, npm 8.5.5 and expo cli 5.4.12

I also saw expo status website and everything seems fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I just randomly started getting this when I run my dev script via npm run dev `export NODE_ENV=development&& expo start -c` but when I just run `expo start` it works fine.

Comment: @MatthewKline I Just copy the files to new project and it ran so I don't know what exactly happened. I think that my internet connection was causing the problem because that happened when my connection was lost and after that I continuously faced that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do a yarn install when I got that, which fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is network issue. My quick solution was to ran `yarn expo start --offline`. But after sometime `yarn start` work, i guess when network was back.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npx expo start -c` and it will work again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `expo start` and you should be good to go! Ran into the same issue and this solved it.